# How to create an ArcObjects point with latitude and longitude?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#

I need to add a point in an existing feature class using .NET API of ArcGIS Server 10 in C# (Visual Studio 2008). I'm using a sample from ESRI Resource Center (ArcGIS_SimpleEdit_CSharp). The following shows the portion of the code that creates the new point using X/Y coordinates.

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint aoPoint = 
    serverContext.CreateObject("esriGeometry.Point") as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint;
aoPoint.PutCoords(actionRecord.Location.X, actionRecord.Location.Y);

...

// Create a feature and set its geometry and attributes to those specified by the
// passed-in action record
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
feature.Shape = aoPoint;
feature.set_Value(featureClass.FindField("Name"), actionRecord.name);
feature.set_Value(featureClass.FindField("LocationId"), actionRecord.id);
feature.set_Value(featureClass.FindField(actionRecord.id), "1");
int trackingNumber = feature.OID;

// Commit the new feature to the database
feature.Store();
workspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
```

But I need to use Latitude and Longitude (with decimal precision) instead of X/Y coordinates. How can I do that? Can I just use lat/lon instead of X/Y? Or I have to convert lat/lon to X/Y before assigning feature.Shape?

Comment: Is this a trick question? Can't you just put your lat long coords in the call to the PutCoords Method? e.g. replace actionRecord.Location.X with -123.54678 and actionRecord.Location.Y with 45.890765...

Comment: Oh no, it's not a trick question. I don't know that much about the ESRI Web API and I asked a wrong question. sorry about that. I'm going to update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key missing piece of information here is what spatial reference (coordinate system) your feature class is assigned, and what coordinate system the `actionRecord` coordinates are in. If they are different (which it sounds like they are) you will need to project the point geometry into the feature class's coordinate system.

The [`IGeometry`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGeometry_Interface/002m000001rm000000/), [`IGeometry2`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGeometry2_Interface/002m000001rn000000/) and [`IGeometry5`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGeometry5_Interface/002m000001rv000000/) interfaces all have different projection methods that you should consider. If you require a specific [geographic transformation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Choosing_an_appropriate_transformation/003r00000010000000/) for example, use [`IGeometry2.ProjectEx`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ProjectEx_Method/002m000001rp000000/).

Also be sure to assign your point geometry the correct spatial reference before projecting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to convert Lat/Long to GCS_WGS_1984 coordinate system. I think I should refer esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984 constant for GCS_WGS_1984, but I don't know how to refer to Lat/long coordinate system. Is there any specifice constant to refere to Lat/Long?

Comment: I think it should be esriSRGeoCS_NAD1983 ((Datum NAD 83). Is that right?

Comment: "Lat/long" is not a coordinate system; latitude and longitude are are simply angular units of measurement used by [geographic coordinate systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system) (which both GCS_WGS_1984 and GCS_NAD_1983 are), so no, there is no specific constant to refer to "Lat/Long". Only you can tell us which coordinate systems your data use. If you need to project between GCS_NAD_1983 and GCS_WGS_1984 check out [this page](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/24159) to determine the correct transformation to use.

Comment: Ok I'm sure the coordinate system is GCS_WGS_1984 and when I add a point in X/Y format (like -13069019.954  6268616.389 Meters) everything is fine. But the thing is I have a list of Lon/Lat (like -117.396947, 48.964884) for the same point). How can I use the Lon/Lat instead of X/Y. I'm sorry if you find my question stupid. I'm a newby in GIS Web development.

Comment: Not at all, but there is still some missing information or confusion. There are TWO coordinate systems involved here: the one used by your feature class, and the one used by your list of points. From the sounds of it, your feature class uses a projected coordinate system (since it is in meters, apparently), and your list of input coordinates is in a geographic coordinate system (GCS_WGS_1984?). You need to find out what your feature class's coordinate system is so you can project from one into the other.

Comment: One simple way to do that would be to cast your `featureClass` to [`IGeoDataset`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGeoDataset_Interface/0025000003m6000000/) and read its SpatialReference property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3648/discussion-between-fred-and-blah238)

Comment: I think the Lon/Lat is just a degree version of the same coordinate system in decimal format. Does it make sense?